# Spring JPA - Inheritance in One-to-Many relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to find the best way to model Student/Teacher - Book relationship. Student and Teacher extend Person and each of them can have many books. At the same time, a book can be owned by one single person. Here are my entities:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class Person implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
        name="person_book",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="person_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="book_id")
    )
    private Set<Book> books= new HashSet<Book>();

    public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }

    public void setBooks(Set<Book> books) {
        this.books = books;
    }
}

@Entity
public class Student extends Person {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Student() {
    }
}

@Entity
public class Teacher extends Person {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Teacher() {
    }
}
```

And my repositories:

```
public interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {
}
public interface TeacherRepository extends CrudRepository<Teacher, Long> {
}
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
}
```

My question is what is the best way to model this?

The Hibernate documentation states that the `TABLE_PER_CLASS` strategy has many drawbacks. I am thus trying to avoid it. However, it seems to me that with those two repositories declared, Spring ends up creating two tables.

And should I declare a `Person` also in the `Book`? If so, what is the right way?

Comment: As is, Teacher and Student are two completely different entities, so you need two different join tables. If your goal is to be able to say "here's the ID of a person, show be the books of that person", then Person must be an entity, not a MappedSuperclass. You can then choose between the 3 types of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't declare a `Person` in `Book` for the purposes of a bidirectional relationship because `Person` is not an entity so there is nothing to map back to. I think you would have to make `Person` an entity and not have a `Student` and `Teacher` entity, but instead have a `Role` entity with a `ManyToMany` (unidirectional) association from `Person`. Consider that a `Person` could be both a student and a teacher, so essentially the assumption that they are separate entities seems flawed.

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Role> roles;
    @OneToMany
    private Set<Book> books;
}
```

Has roles and books.

```
@Entity
public class Role {}
```

Defines `STUDENT` and `TEACHER`

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    @ManyToOne
    private Person owner;
}
```

Has an owner.

Comment: I ended up simplifying the model to follow your suggestion. Thanks.